# Android write text in file Sd card

Tags: android, android-sdcard

i try  to write text in file.i wrote code ,witch can  to write text ,but if i will use again my code again text is rewrite in file.for example if i first time write "Hello android" and then  "Sir",result is only "Sir".i want "Hello android Sir"

```
your_file = new File("/sdcard/facebookUser");

                try {
                    Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(
                            your_file), "UTF-8");
                    writer.write(facebook_user_name + ",");
                    writer.write(facebook_id);
                    writer.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if (writer != null) {
                        try {
                            writer.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
```

how i can write code to save another text in this file second time?

Comment: You're using .write - Try .append(string) instead

Comment: what is a solution in your option ?

Comment: Use StringBuilder to handle this

Answer (score 0):

```
new FileOutputStream(your_file, true)
```

`public FileOutputStream(String name, boolean append) throws FileNotFoundException`

append - if true, then bytes will be written to the end of the file rather than the beginning

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(
                            your_file), "UTF-8");
```

Use:

```
writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(
                            your_file, true), "UTF-8");
```

This sets the `FileOutputStream` in append mode.

> java.io.FileOutputStream.FileOutputStream(File file, boolean append)
>   throws FileNotFoundException
>
> Constructs a new FileOutputStream that writes to file. If append is
>   true and the file already exists, it will be appended to; otherwise it
>   will be truncated. The file will be created if it does not exist.

Comment: i  changed this source,but now i want to add some text in this file with another activity.i wore this code in another activity Registration.writer.append("Hello");
      Registration.writer.close();

Comment: did you first check about this part of your question: ".. code to save another text in this file second time?" . From one activity...if you wrote the content twice..did it append in the same file? then that part is fixed.. Moving to another activity, something else could be a problem..

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
        int n = 0;
        String Name = "file";
        File myFile = new File("/sdcard/test/");
        if (!myFile.exists()) {
            boolean b = myFile.mkdirs(); }
        myFile = new File("/sdcard/test/"+Name+".txt");
        while (myFile.exists())
        {
            myFile = new File("/sdcard/test/"+Name+n+".txt");  
            n++;
        }
        myFile.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
        OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
        String str = "Your text to write";
        myOutWriter.append(str);
        myOutWriter.close();
        fOut.close();
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

And do not forget permision:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: the first time write isn't a problem, so its not the permission or the rest of the code :)

Comment: Ok, you should read old file (get String), then OldString+NewString and override old file

Comment: doesn't matter, if the file already exists, new text will be appended.  
And even otherwise, logically it doesn't seem optimum to 'oldstring+newstring'..just saying

Answer (score 0):

Vladimir Kulyk and user2450263 are correct! You have to write a file in append mode. try [this](http://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/qanda/pjqa00009.shtml) link.